# Djoser / Django Rest Framework / User Registration: How to store non required user fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using **Djoser** and **Django Rest Framework** for user registration with a custom user model. When I try to add NON REQUIRED fields  to my custom user models and pass them (as **kwargs) , these additional fields do not get saved.

Is this by design or is there a trick to saving these?

```
    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

        def create_user(self, email, phone, password, **kwargs):
            user = self.model(
                email=email,
                phone=phone,
                **kwargs
            )

            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user

        def create_superuser(self, email, phone, password, **kwargs):
            user = self.model(
                email=email,
                phone=phone,
                is_staff=True,
                is_active=True,
                **kwargs
            )

            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user

    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45, null=False)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, null=False)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        is_active = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'User'

        objects = UserManager()

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone']

        def get_full_name(self):
            return self.email
        def get_short_name(self):
            return self.email
        def natural_key(self):
            return self.email
        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
```

Comment: can you show how your are passing **kwargs to create_user?

Comment: Looks like this is a known Djoser issue and there is a workaround as mentioned here; https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/issues/249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known Djoser issue and there is a workaround as mentioned here; github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/issues/249